# MySQL Arabic Character Encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I want to insert Arabic data in MySQL database. I tried to change the table encoding to UTF-8 using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE `t` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I also tried the collation utf8_bin and I changed it in the my-default.ini file (on Windows) but all what I am getting are characters like this: Ï¡┘àÏºÏ»Ï®

This is an example of what I am getting:

```
Value inserted   ||   Value selected  ||  Hex value selected
دددد             ||  Ï»Ï»Ï»Ï»         || C38FC2BBC38FC2BBC38FC2BBC38FC2BB
rrr              ||    rrr            || 727272
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: The problem was solved by editing mysql files. See the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

After checking where mysqld gets the default options from using the command:

```
mysqld --help --verbose > temp_file_path
```

In the temp file, I found that it gets the default options as stated below:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.cnf
```

None of these files were found on my machine, so I had to rename the file 'my-default.ini' to 'my.ini'. Adding the correct encoding to the file, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have now made things worse.  That looks like "double encoding".  But I am not sure.  Please provide `SELECT col, hex(col) ...` for some sample, plus what it should look like.

Several things are needed for making `CHARACTER SET` work right in MySQL.  Let's say you want to be entirely utf8 (or utf8mb4), which is the 'right' thing to do.

- Have utf8-encoded bytes in your client.  This is a function of how you get the data.
- Tell mysqld that your client's bytes are utf8 by saying `SET NAMES utf8` (or equivalent, depending on the client's library).
- Declare the table columns to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  (Usually the table default suffices.)
- If writing to a web page, have `<meta ... utf8>`.

If you can start over, that might be best.  If not,... 
All of this, and more, including how to fix double-encoding, is found in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

Comment: This is an example of what I am getting:

Value inserted   ||   Value selected  ||  Hex value selected
دددد    ||     Ï»Ï»Ï»Ï»  || C38FC2BBC38FC2BBC38FC2BBC38FC2BB
 
rrr     ||       rrr       || 727272

Comment: I'm looking for the HEX().

Comment: Strange.  r=72, no problem.  But `د` should be `D8AF`.  For "double encoding" (latin1 vs utf8), I would expect `D8`->`Ø`->`C398`->`Ã˜` and `AF`->`¥`->`C2A5`->`Â¥`.  The bottom line:  You have a case which I am no familiar with.  Were you ever using something other than `utf8` or `latin1`?  Any more clues about how you got to where you are?

Comment: The default encoding is cp850, this causes the characters to be changed this way د -> Ï» . I tried to change the character set client to utf8 but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Aha.  I was looking at latin1, not cp850.  How did you solve it?

Comment: Just renaming the 'my-default.ini' file to 'my.ini' solved the problem.